# Show multiple CollectionView Cell in single column respectively to its section in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I have 4 section in collection view so i take 4 collectionviewcell. when numberOfItemsInSection increases it shows in next row but i want to show in same section in single column separately. It's scrolling direction is vertically.

Here the image where i am working.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyVOh.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LDHZ.png)

```
import UIKit

class CollectionVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate , 
UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {



@IBOutlet weak var collectionView:UICollectionView!


var englishArray = ["You", "Apple" , "Me" , "Developer",  "Phone" , "Time"]
var hindiArray = ["आप","सेब","मैं","डेवलपर","फ़ोन","समय"]

var emptyArray = ["1","2","3","4","5","6"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}


func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 4
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
    if section == 0 {
        return englishArray.count
    } else if section == 1 {
        return englishArray.count
    } else if section == 2 {
        return englishArray.count
    } else {
        return englishArray.count
    }
    
    
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        
        let  Cell  =  collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "EnglishCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! EnglishCollectionViewCell
        return Cell
        
        
        
    } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
        
        let  Cell  =  collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "AnswerCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! AnswerCollectionViewCell
        return Cell
    } else if indexPath.section == 2 {
        
        let  Cell  =  collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "StatusCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! StatusCollectionViewCell
        return Cell
    } else {
        
        let  Cell  =  collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "HindiCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! HindiCollectionViewCell
        return Cell
    }
    
    
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
{

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        

        let width  = (view.frame.width-10)/4
        return CGSize(width: width, height: width)
        
        
    } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
        let width  = (view.frame.width-10)/4
        return CGSize(width: width, height: width)

      
    } else if indexPath.section == 2 {
        let width  = (view.frame.width-10)/4
        return CGSize(width: width, height: width)

      
    } else {
        let width  = (view.frame.width-10)/4
        return CGSize(width: width, height: width)
    }
    
      
}


@IBAction func resetButton(sender:UIButton) {
    hindiArray.shuffle()
    collectionView.reloadData()
    
}
```

}

Please help me out to solve this solve this issue.

Comment: when items are more then 4 in that case you want to do horizontal scroll or anything else?

Comment: i want vertical scroll in collection-view

Comment: what if there are more then 4 in each section ?

Comment: please see this image you will that how i want to make - [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LDHZ.png

Comment: for it you have to add horizontal collectionview inside vortical collectionview cell

Answer (score 0):

for your desired output you have to use concept of nested collectionview.
in simple language you have to use collectionview inside collectionviewcell.

here we have `mainCollectionView`. Then on each cell of this collection create and initialize a new `UICollectionView` and right place to do that is in this following delegate of UICollectionView

e.g I initialize the `MainCollectionViewCell` here and then `MainCollectionViewCell` handles the logic to create a new `UICollectionView`

```
guard let collectionViewCell = cell as? MainCollectionViewCell else { return }
    
    collectionViewCell.delegate = self
    
    let dataProvider = ChildCollectionViewDataSource()
    dataProvider.data = data[indexPath.row] as NSArray
    
    let delegate = ChildCollectionViewDelegate()
    
    collectionViewCell.initializeCollectionViewWithDataSource(dataProvider, delegate: delegate, forRow: indexPath.row)
    
    collectionViewCell.collectionViewOffset = storedOffsets[indexPath.row] ?? 0
```

Here is the initializer on `MainCollectionViewCell` that creates a new `UICollectionView`

```
func initializeCollectionViewWithDataSource<D: protocol<UICollectionViewDataSource>,E: protocol<UICollectionViewDelegate>>(dataSource: D, delegate :E, forRow row: Int) {
    
    self.collectionViewDataSource = dataSource
    
    self.collectionViewDelegate = delegate
    
    let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    flowLayout.scrollDirection = .Horizontal
    
    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.bounds, collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
    collectionView.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseChildCollectionViewCellIdentifier)
    collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    collectionView.dataSource = self.collectionViewDataSource
    collectionView.delegate = self.collectionViewDelegate
    collectionView.tag = row
    
    self.addSubview(collectionView)
    
    self.collectionView = collectionView
            
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Hope it will be help you... :)

you can also refer full code from :- https://github.com/irfanlone/Collection-View-in-a-collection-view-cell

Comment: you can upvote or tick it right .. welcome:)